# Minimal variance for an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, observables

For an operator $Q$, the variance is given by: $$\left\langle Q^2 \right\rangle - \left\langle Q \right\rangle^2$$ If the eigenvalue equation for the operator is given by $$\hat{Q} |q_i \rangle = q_i |q_i \rangle $$ for $i = 1,2,3, \ldots N$ where $N$ is finite. How can we find the minimum variance? (All we know about the operator given is that it is self-adjoint or hermitian conjugate)

Comment: Hint: Think about what's the operational meaning of variance. It quantifies the variation in the outcomes of your experiment of measuring an operator over many many identically prepared copies of a state. So, can there be such a state for which all the measurements of the operator would give the same outcome (and thus, the variance would vanish)? If yes, what would be such a state? If you convince yourself that such a state exists then you've convinced yourself that the minimum variance is zero.

Comment: I agree! The minimal variance must be 0. The question I have is how would we show that using the eigenstates and the eigenvalues? Like, instead of minimum variance if the question asks for maximal variance, how would one use the information given to find an abstract definition for it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Write $$(\Delta_\psi Q)^2 := \langle Q^2\rangle_\psi - \langle Q\rangle_\psi ^2= \langle (Q-\langle Q\rangle_\psi \mathbb I)^2\rangle_\psi  = \langle (Q-\langle Q\rangle_\psi \mathbb I)\, \psi,(Q-\langle Q\rangle_\psi \mathbb I)\,\psi\rangle \quad ,$$

where $\langle \cdot \rangle_\psi:= \langle \psi,\cdot\, \psi\rangle$  denotes the expectation value in the (normalized) state $\psi$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the corresponding inner product. Use its definition to show that $(\Delta_\psi Q)^2 =0 $ if and only if $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $Q$.
Since $(\Delta_\psi Q)^2 \geq 0$, this is the minimum value.

For a more mathematical treatment (e.g. discussing the validity of the equations, domains etc.), cf.
*Quantum Theory for Mathematicians, chapter 12. Hall. Springer*.

Comment: Jason, thanks so much for this explanation! How would one go about solving for maximum value of this operator then?

Comment: Dear @MichaelShaw Sorry, but I really don't know if one can say something about this in general.